# Can't get a simple save with SharedPreferences to work - what am I missing?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save an int with SharedPreferences: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

However, when I run the code below, it only prints "Hello" and not "Here".
It seems to get stuck at the "final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();"
What is going on? Am I missing something?

```
...
class _InventoryItemState extends State<InventoryItem> {


  Future <void> saveInt() async {

    print("hello");
    // obtain shared preferences
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print("Here");


    // set value
    prefs.setInt('counter', 7);

    // load value
    final counter = prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 2;

    print(counter);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    saveInt();
...
```

UPDATE:

Got it to work by using this code:

'''

```
_saveInvNumber() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'invNumber';
    final value = widget.invNumber;
    prefs.setInt(key, value);
    print('saved $value');
  }
```

'''

Comment: Have you no any error after `hello`?

Comment: No I do not, no error messages

Comment: When using shared preferences, setting data is a future that you should use the await keyword for, while getting data is not a future so you can just access the data immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the SharedPreferences dependecies in pubspec.yaml.If not here's how you do it:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
```

The problem from your code is you make `SharedPreferences` `final` which I believe you can't change the value from it. Here's exmaple how to save string value:

```
addStringToSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('stringValue', "abc");
}
```

Comment: I got it to work with some other code, but I still do not understand why that works and not the other.